# Show loader and disable button on submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqxwidgets

I am using the following code to show a loader and disable button when the form is submitted.

I have my form in a popup and in chrome the button gets disabled when my popup is closed. I need to disable button when user clicks the submit button.

```
 $('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') > -1){
        $("body").append($('<div id="imageloader" class="loader"><img id="spinner" src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Spinner" /></div>'));
    }else{
        $('#imageloader').css('display','block'); 
    } 
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    $(this).css({"opacity":".2","cursor":"progress"}); 
    $("#hideWindowButton").attr("Click", "return false;"); // disabled cancel button 
    $("#hideWindowButton").css({"opacity":".2","cursor":"progress"}); 
});
```

Comment: I have made some edits to your text - since I'm not 100% sure what you meant, please make sure it still makes sense.

Comment: I m not getting what changes you have made?
if you can help me i'll appreciate..

Comment: To the left of your signature (right above these comments) there should be a note saying "edited [time] ago" - click that and you can compare the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> ```
> $('input[type=submit]').click(function(event) {
> event.preventDefault();
> if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') > -1) {
>     $("body").append($('<div id="imageloader" class="loader"><img id="spinner" src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Spinner" /></div>'));
> } else {
>     $('#imageloader').css('display', 'block');
> }
> $(this).prop("disabled", true);
> $(this).closest('form').submit();
> $(this).css({
>     "opacity": ".2",
>     "cursor": "progress"
> });
> $("#hideWindowButton").attr("click", "return false;"); // disabled cancel button 
> $("#hideWindowButton").css({
>     "opacity": ".2",
>     "cursor": "progress"
> }); });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

if you add onclick event inline in your submit like this:

```
<input type='submit' value='submit' onclick="$(this).prop('disabled',true)" />
```

suits you?

Comment: if I put inside on submit then it has to be submitted before it disable
I don't want that I want 2 actions to run at the same time..not one after the other

Comment: I cannot add it in submit button

Comment: @user3913769 why so? ))

Comment: coz i am not allowed to change in the form... i ned to doen it with the help of jquery without making change in html.. and i need to make my loader working too.. which i cann't define there